# Application Gateway’s ARRAffinity cookie domain does not match with site’s domain

Tags: azure, asp.net

I have configured an Application Gateway with the cookie-based affinity following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-powershell).

The backend pool is configured as abc.azurewebsites.net.

I have created a CNAME test.example.com to point to the domain of Application Gateway. Now, when I browse test.example.com, the ARRAffinity cookie has the domain name same as the backend pool (abc.azurewebsites.net). It looks like because of this cookie domain name, the sticky session is not working.

Can I override this cookie domain name to math to the site’s domain name to make the sticky session work?

Any other advice to make the sticky session work here?

[cookie domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NK6O.png)